# How to get the layer details in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a layer which is defined as following

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
avg_pool = layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)
```

Is there a way to print the details of this layer? (in this case it would be printing the `pool_size`)?
I cannot use summary on this layer as it gives me
`AttributeError: 'AveragePooling1D' object has no attribute 'summary'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.summary` is available for [`model` class](https://keras.io/api/models/model/#summary:%7E:text=%5Bsource%5D-,summary%20method,-Model.summary) and not `layer`. That's why you can't do `avg_pool.summary()`. But you can wrap it into model class.

```py
avg_pool = layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)
avg_pool.pool_size
(2,)

# init model 
model = keras.Sequential([avg_pool])

# run on some dummy tensor to build the model
x = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
x = np.reshape(x, [1, 5, 1])
_ = model(x)

# print summary
model.summary() # OK
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print the details of the layer by accessing its attributes directly. In the case of the AveragePooling1D layer, you can print the pool_size attribute like this:

```html
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

avg_pool = layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2)

# Print the pool_size
print("Pool Size:", avg_pool.pool_size)
```